# Why doesn't gcc support naked functions?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I use naked functions to patch parts of a program while it's running. I can easily do this in VC++ in Windows. I'm trying to do this in Linux and it seems gcc doesn't support naked functions. Compiling code with naked functions gives me this: warning: ‘naked’ attribute directive ignored. Compiled under CentOS 5.5 i386.

Comment: This seems to be a particular feature of VC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21d5kd3a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6):

The naked attribute is only supported by GCC on certain platforms (ARM, AVR, MCORE, RX and SPU) according to the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> **`naked`**:
>   Use this attribute on the ARM, AVR, MCORE, RX and SPU ports to
>   indicate that the specified function does not need prologue/epilogue
>   sequences generated by the compiler. It is up to the programmer to
>   provide these sequences. The only statements that can be safely
>   included in naked functions are asm statements that do not have
>   operands. All other statements, including declarations of local
>   variables, if statements, and so forth, should be avoided. Naked
>   functions should be used to implement the body of an assembly
>   function, while allowing the compiler to construct the requisite
>   function declaration for the assembler.

I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why do you need to only use asm statements that don't have operands? Don't nearly all commands have operands (even things like `jmp` take an operand)?

Comment: @Seth: the instructions used in the assembler code can have operands, but an "asm statement" doesn't mean the assembler instruction, it's the whole `asm ("some insns" : outputblah : inputblah : clobberblah);`. The "blahs" are the operands of the asm statement, and that's what you can't use if you don't have the compiler-generated prologue. You can write assembler, but you can't hook it up to C variables.

Answer (score 6):

**=== Update ===**

As of 2023 they do work:

```
__attribute__((naked))    
void my_write(int fd, char const* str, int size) {
    asm
    (
    "       pusha                              \n\t"
    "       movl   $4, %eax                    \n\t"
    "       movl   36(%esp), %ebx              \n\t"
    "       movl   40(%esp), %ecx              \n\t"
    "       movl   44(%esp), %edx              \n\t"
    "       int    $0x80                       \n\t"
    "       popa                               \n\t"
    "       ret                                \n\t"
    );
}

void _start() {
    my_write(1, "hi\n", 3);
    my_write(1, "bye\n", 4);
}
```

compiled with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib my_write.c` using `gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)`

**=== Old answer ===**

On x86 you can workaround by using asm at global scope instead:

```
void my_write(int fd, const void *buf, int count);                                            
                                                                                 
asm                                                                              
(                                                                                
".global my_write                          \n\t"
"my_write:                                 \n\t"
"       pusha                              \n\t"
"       movl   $4, %eax                    \n\t"
"       movl   36(%esp), %ebx              \n\t"
"       movl   40(%esp), %ecx              \n\t"
"       movl   44(%esp), %edx              \n\t"
"       int    $0x80                       \n\t"
"       popa                               \n\t"
"       ret                                \n\t"
);

void _start()
{
    my_write(1, "hi\n", 3);
    my_write(1, "bye\n", 4);
}
```

Also `naked` is listed among [x86 function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html), so I suppose it works for newer gcc.

Answer (score 1):

GCC only supports naked functions on ARM and other embedded platforms. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Also, what you're doing is inherently unsafe, as you cannot guarantee that the code you're patching isn't executing if the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

That's an ugly solution. Link against a .asm file for your target architecture.