# Obtain static variable address encapsulated in namespace

Tags: c++, assembly

I have two files similar to this:

## a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int hack();

typedef int (*hackFunction)();

namespace secret
{
    static int mysecret;
    int _main(hackFunction hack)
    {
        cin >> mysecret;
        assert(hack() == mysecret);
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    return secret::_main(hack);
}
```

## b.cpp

```
int hack()
{
    return 31;
}
```

I am not able to edit a.cpp.
I want to write such hack() function so that it would be able to obtain mysecret value from b.cpp(I think it should be done by obtaining its address). Are there any ways to do that?

I tried to disassemble the file. Seems like mysecret is stored in 0x0(%%rip), so we can obtain it if we can obtain %%rip register state when mysecret is being cin'ed.

Comment: You can obtain in in `main` like `secret::mysecret`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `namespace secret { extern static int mysecret; }` in b.cpp?

Comment: @VTT, yeah, but I want to do it in another file. I will clarify it.

Comment: @JVApen, yes, but static specifier conflicts with extern specifier, so such code won't compile.

Comment: Just make `hack` return a reference to `mysecret` then? What is the actual problem with writing this hack function?

Comment: @VTT, I don't get it, mysecret is not accessible from b.cpp, because it is placed in a.cpp inside the secret namespace.

Comment: This whole question seems to be an X/Y problem. Doing trickery to get an address of static variable in some random translation unit is not a sane programming concern. If that static variable is declared that way and there is no getter function then most likely this variable is not supposed to be used (or even known) from outside.

Comment: not related, but for readability consider using a different name for your _main `hackFunction` parameter, i.e. different from `hack` function name

Comment: @VTT, I've got a task. There is file given that is more complicated version of a.cpp with several variables. My task is to write b.cpp that solves certain problem with given arguments, but I know the answer is stored in mysecret.cpp so I wonder is there any way to get it without solving this problem.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to crack a game, or something  (e.g. bypass cheat protection).

Answer (score 1):

It is compilation-specific. 
You do not provide disassembly, so I use gcc 7.2 for example
(https://godbolt.org/g/oUAvcG), line 10-15:

```
mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:secret::mysecret ; move mysecret (value of address) to ESI 
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cin ; pass handle to stdout
call std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&) ; print mysecret
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] ; move hack() address to RAX 
call rax ; calls to hack() by register
```

We're not able to know offset to it from code we can write (`b.cpp`)
`RIP` register only shows location of next instuction to processor, but not `mysecret` address.
If you now calling convention of `hack()` than you can only determine the return address. If `mysecret` was constant, offset from return address will be your answer, but you have only address and must return value of it.
If `hack()` is `cdecl`, than return address will be at `ESP` at start of `hack()`
Calculate the difference in bytes between address on 10 line and 16 line, and get  it value. So, hack() will be like this:

```
int __naked hack()
{
  __asm
  {
     mov ecx, esp ; return value in main() after hack() is called
     sub ecx, <value> ; <value> is the constant offset to mysecret address
     mov eax, [ecx] ; read mysecret address hardcoded in assembly 
     mov eax, [eax] ; return mysecret value
     ret ; extiting subroutine
  }
}
```

Also,

Comment: Note that Godbolt demangles C++ symbol names by default.  If you disable that, you can see what symbol name `secret::mysecret` really has.

Comment: @peter-cordes there will be address at last

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't quite understand this sentence: "than return address will be at ESP at start of hack()". Could you explain return address of what are you talking about? Also, we are talking about the case when mysecret is constant, right?

Comment: By the way, isn't mysecret stored in .data section so I can apply something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383393/getting-address-of-data-variable-in-x86-att-assembly

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, use reply option(@). I mean that `ESP` processor register will contain address of line 15 at `secret::_main()` function  (https://godbolt.org/g/oUAvcG) - this is the next instruction to execute after `hack()` returns. "At the start" i mean that there will be prologue in compiled version of `hack()` function - usually `push ebp`, `mov ebp, esp` that will change `ESP` value (`ESP` will contain pushed to stack old `EBP` value).
To tell compiler not to add prologue, use `__naked` keyword in `hack()` definition.

Comment: @PrimeApe I think I've understood something, but you take the value with address (esp - C), as I can understand, it is a variable on stack or an address of function. Why should mysecret be there?

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, Saying about that but do not write it in answer. You're right, mov eax, [ecx] will read *address* of `secret::mysecret` (in assembly `mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:of secret::_main()` that address will be hardcoded after compilation of `a.cpp`). Now we must read value with `mov eax, [eax]` (added this to answer)

Comment: @PrimeApe Well, I've got two questions then. At first, it is strange for me that mysecret address equals to the main address. Is it correct? The second question, am I right that if you write __naked function than you should write prologue by yourself?

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, It is *not* equal. Follow this: `ESP` contains addres of instruction that will be executed after `hack()`'s `ret`. We know that address will be *in* `main()` (address of line 15), but *not* `main()` address. Also we know about there is address of `mysecret` just handful of bytes before  (line 10, there will be opcode bytes of `mov esi, offset <address>`. In hex it will be `0xbe 0x<address in big endian>`. Then, if you calculate difference between line 15 and ((line 10) + 1) you can obtain `mysecret` address, just by doing `sub ecx, <difference>`

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, 2nd question: yes, you must, but if you doing almost nothing (no stack variables or parameters) in you naked function, there is no need to write prologue and epilogue. It's *not correct*, but it's a hack!. Also, you may choose another calling convention, implementation of `hack()` will be a little more difficult.

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, if you have questions, feel free to ask, if this answer is helpful, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @PrimeApe, sorry for being offline for so long. Actually, I didn't quite understand what is going on. I tried to write this function, but I couldn't apply __naked attribute. Compiler says it is being ignored. Here is the code, but it gives me "Command terminated" message. https://pastebin.com/WShAJNZ7

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov, hey! A year and a half has passed! Here's your answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278234/why-doesnt-gcc-support-naked-functions

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is for your function to get the variable like that(if it has access to it):

```
int hack()
{
    return secret::mysecret;
}
```

Another way is like you said to pass a pointer to the variable to the function like this:

```
int hack(int *secret)
{
    return *secret;
}
```

And pass it in when you call it like that:

```
assert(hack(&mysecret) == mysecret);
```

You will have to change the signatures like that:

```
int hack(int *);

typedef int (*hackFunction)(int *);
int _main(hackFunction hack)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not able to edit a.cpp. I should clarify it in the question.

Comment: If the function doesn't have access to the variable and you can't pass in the address then how are you expecting to get it?

Comment: First possible solution is something like JVAPEN suggested - to write something similar to extern variable. Second solution I thought about is to disassemble the program and get the relative address. I think it is possible because variable is static so it is stored in .data section.